# Is it correct and natural to say "my phone holds a charge well" meaning it has a good battery"?

Tags: collocations

Could you tell me if it's natural to say *my phone holds a charge well* in the sense its battery last long enough? For example:

> One of the most valuable advantages of my phone is the fact the **it holds a charge well**.

If sounds off, could you provide options native English speakers would say to communicate the message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "holds a charge well" could be used, but it doesn't directly address how long it lasts. It's more common to say "My phone has [a] good battery life.", where "a" is optional.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Could you tell what "hold a charge well" then mean?

Comment: "Holds a charge well" is more apt for saying that it has low self-discharge:  that once charged, the battery will stay charged a long time if the phone is left turned off or unused.